# Kiom da lingvoj Zamenhof povas paroli?

Tags: language

Mi verkas artikolon pri Zamenhof, kaj scivolas pri tiu informo.

Comment: Bonvenon al Stack Exchange! :-)

Answer (score 4):

> He appears to have been natively bilingual in Yiddish and Russian (Polish language was restricted and forbidden in public conversations by the Tsarist authorities),[4] presumably the Belarusian "dialect" of his home town, though it may have been only his father who spoke Russian with him at home. From his father, a teacher of German and French, he learned those languages and Hebrew as well. Despite this he spoke Polish, one of the major languages of Białystok alongside Yiddish, Belarusian, and German, and it was Polish that was to become the native language of his children after settling in the Kingdom of Poland. In school he studied the classical languages: Latin, Greek, Hebrew, and Aramaic. He later learned some English, though in his own words not very well, had an interest in Lithuanian and Italian, and learned Volapük when it came out in 1880, though by that point his international language project was already well developed.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._L._Zamenhof